# Wordpress stylesheet not loading

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

**SOLUTION**

The problem was that I didn't include the header on index.php

```
<?php
    get_header();
?>
```

I added this on the first line of index.php, removing the opening  and  tags and it started working.

**ORIGINAL POST**

I know this has been posted about already, but none of the solutions I try seem to be working.

I am trying to load a stylesheet for my wordpress theme, but it doesn't seem to be working. My stylesheet is named `style.css` and it resides in the root folder (the theme folder), alongside `index.php`, `header.php`, `footer.php` and `functions.php`.

**Edit:** Using the firefox debugger shows that the stylesheet is definitely not loading. The style editor section gives me a, "This page has no stylesheet."

Here are the contents of those files:

**index.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css"/>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

**style.css**

```
body{
    background-color: green;
    background: green;
}
```

**header.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <?php wp_head();?>
</head> 
</html>
```

**footer.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
<body>
    <footer class="site-footer"></footer>
    <?php wp_footer(); ?>
</body>
</html>
```

**functions.php**

```
<?php
    function load_css(){
        wp_enqueue_style('styles',get_stylesheet_uri());
    }
    add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'load_css');
?>
```

Comment: Try `href="/style.css"`  (with a slash)

Comment: Are you working Child theme?

Comment: @clota974 Still nothing unfortunately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I didn't include the header on index.php

```
<?php
    get_header();
?>
```

I added this on the first line of index.php, removing the opening  and  tags and it started working.

Answer (score 0):

Your templates are being used incorrectly. You should not be starting and ending a complete HTML document in each of these files.

**Template Hierarchy**

WordPress will compose a page for you by using the sub-templates `header.php` at the top, `footer.php` at the bottom, and with the appropriate template in between. Very important to note the template hierarchy in WordPress. Different template parts will be called for based on which view is being rendered. Any good theme has a variety of templates for different contexts and purposes. Read: https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/.

**Example**

Your blog will be rendered like this:

```
header.php

index.php

footer.php
```

A single blog post will use this:

```
header.php

single.php

footer.php
```

A page will use this:

```
header.php

page.php

footer.php
```

etc...

**Theming**

A good idea is to take a look at the contents of these files in a default WordPress theme, note how the document is started in header.php, and is closed in footer.php. Follow this and your stylesheet will be enqueued as expected. More reading on themes: https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/getting-started/what-is-a-theme/

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I looked through the link and I made the changes (header.php starts the <html> and <head> tags and stops after wp_head() with the <head> tag still open, index.php closes the <head> tag and starts the <body> tag, and footer.php closes the <body> and <html> tags), but still nothing.

Answer (score 0):

The stylesheet URI you are enqueueing in `functions.php`, doesn't look complete to me. This bit:

`get_stylesheet_uri()`

This will just get the directory of the of the stylesheet, which is usually the root directory of the theme. You need to point to the specific stylesheet, so your function would look like this:

```
function load_css(){
  wp_enqueue_style('styles', get_stylesheet_uri() . '/style.css' );
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'load_css');
```

...where `. '/styles.css'` is completing the path to the stylesheet file. Make sure the file name matches.

Resource: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_stylesheet_uri/

Sorry I didnt see notice that the first time My other answer still applies for the templating issues I saw the first time.

Comment: From what I understand, get_stylesheet_uri() defaults the search to "style.css" in the root folder. I still tried it though, with no luck unfortunately.